# How to do bulk SVG operations with SVG.js

Tags: typescript, svg, svg.js

Im using SVG.js to create a group that has a lot of rectangles and paths and texts as a child. This group represents a data object visually. Now if data changes the texts and fills change also. One screen there can be many manyof these objects and they can be added tynamically. So the time to update the SVG is slow. I was thinking if there is a way to improve the redraw speed of SVG. My first thought was doing bulk operations. Like i create the structure of the SVG before hand and then in bulk pace them in the DOM so that it would do the update in one go.

Is there a way to do bulk operations with SVG.js or maybe any other way to improve the performance of SVG while retaining the ability to change text contents? I thought about using defs but i have some variable amount subcomponents whose location is dependand on the amount of elements needed to show.

Here is the SVG i create using SVG.js. This currently has only test data, but in real use the TSpan data would be user defined and the amount of the text elements is also dependant on userinput. And in the end the final 4 path, would have fill colors depending on user input. Is this possible in SVG or do i need to keep recreating thhis object every time i want a new one with different data?

```
<g id="SvgjsG1010" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,1197,241)">
<circle id="SvgjsCircle1011" r="42" cx="22" cy="19"></circle>
<rect id="SvgjsRect1012" width="45" height="48" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
<rect id="SvgjsRect1013" width="45" height="4" x="0" y="48" fill="#09a583" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
<text id="SvgjsText1014" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="15.900000095367432" y="46.200000166893005">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1015" dy="5.2" x="15.900000095367432">Owner</tspan>
</text>
<text id="SvgjsText1016" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="18.09999990463257" y="1.0000001668930052">
    <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1017" dy="5.2" x="18.09999990463257">Test</tspan>
</text>
<g id="SvgjsG1018">
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1019" width="10" height="10" x="5" y="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1020" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="5" y="11.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1021" dy="5.2" x="5">Note</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1022" width="10" height="10" x="17" y="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1023" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="17" y="11.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1024" dy="5.2" x="17">Note</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1025" width="10" height="10" x="29" y="10" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1026" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="29" y="11.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1027" dy="5.2" x="29">Note</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1028" width="10" height="10" x="5" y="22" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1029" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="5" y="23.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1030" dy="5.2" x="5">Note</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1031" width="10" height="10" x="17" y="22" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1032" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="17" y="23.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1033" dy="5.2" x="17">Note</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1034" width="10" height="10" x="29" y="22" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1035" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="29" y="23.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1036" dy="5.2" x="29">Note</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1037" width="10" height="10" x="5" y="34" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1038" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="5" y="35.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1039" dy="5.2" x="5">Note</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1040" width="10" height="10" x="17" y="34" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1041" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="17" y="35.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1042" dy="5.2" x="17">Note</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1043" width="10" height="10" x="29" y="34" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1044" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="29" y="35.200000166893005">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1045" dy="5.2" x="29">Note</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
<g id="SvgjsG1046">
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1047" width="15" height="4" x="0" y="-4" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1048" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="2.9000000953674316" y="-5.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1049" dy="5.2" x="2.9000000953674316">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1050" width="15" height="4" x="15" y="-4" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1051" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="17.90000009536743" y="-5.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1052" dy="5.2" x="17.90000009536743">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1053" width="15" height="4" x="30" y="-4" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1054" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="32.90000009536743" y="-5.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1055" dy="5.2" x="32.90000009536743">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1056" width="15" height="4" x="0" y="-8" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1057" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="2.9000000953674316" y="-9.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1058" dy="5.2" x="2.9000000953674316">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1059" width="15" height="4" x="15" y="-8" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1060" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="17.90000009536743" y="-9.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1061" dy="5.2" x="17.90000009536743">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1062" width="15" height="4" x="30" y="-8" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1063" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="32.90000009536743" y="-9.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1064" dy="5.2" x="32.90000009536743">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1065" width="15" height="4" x="0" y="-12" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1066" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="2.9000000953674316" y="-13.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1067" dy="5.2" x="2.9000000953674316">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1068" width="15" height="4" x="15" y="-12" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1069" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="17.90000009536743" y="-13.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1070" dy="5.2" x="17.90000009536743">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1071" width="15" height="4" x="30" y="-12" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1072" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="32.90000009536743" y="-13.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1073" dy="5.2" x="32.90000009536743">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1074" width="15" height="4" x="0" y="-16" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1075" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="2.9000000953674316" y="-17.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1076" dy="5.2" x="2.9000000953674316">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1077" width="15" height="4" x="15" y="-16" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1078" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="17.90000009536743" y="-17.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1079" dy="5.2" x="17.90000009536743">User</tspan>
    </text>
    <rect id="SvgjsRect1080" width="15" height="4" x="30" y="-16" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5"></rect>
    <text id="SvgjsText1081" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="4" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="4" x="32.90000009536743" y="-17.799999833106995">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1082" dy="5.2" x="32.90000009536743">User</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
<g id="SvgjsG1083" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-2,0)">
    <circle id="SvgjsCircle1084" r="4.1" cx="0" cy="0"></circle>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1085" d="M0 0 0 4 A4 4 0 0 1 -4 0 Z" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.1"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1086" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="2" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="2" x="-3" y="0.10000008344650269">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1087" dy="2.6" x="-3">T</tspan>
    </text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1088" d="M0 0 4 0 A4 4 0 0 1 0 4 Z" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.1"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1089" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="2" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="2" x="1" y="0.10000008344650269">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1090" dy="2.6" x="1">C</tspan>
    </text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1091" d="M0 0 -4 0 A4 4 0 0 1 0 -4 Z" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.1"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1092" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="2" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="2" x="-2.899999976158142" y="-3.8999999165534973">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1093" dy="2.6" x="-2.899999976158142">F</tspan>
    </text>
    <path id="SvgjsPath1094" d="M0 0 0 -4 A4 4 0 0 1 4 0 Z" fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.1"></path>
    <text id="SvgjsText1095" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="2" fill="#000000" family="Helvetica" size="2" x="1" y="-3.8999999165534973">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1096" dy="2.6" x="1">A</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
</g>
```

Comment: You can create svg nodes outside of the dom and inject them later.
However, some methods will not work when a node is not attached to the dom.

For example moving text around by default uses the bbox to position the text by its upper left corner. However, you can get around that by positioning the text by its baseline instead (which is the normal x and y coordinates of text).
As long as you only use the attr()-method you are on the save side!

However, no lib can give you the performance of vanilla js. So if you need to do this stuff really fast, try to write a vanilla function yourself!

Comment: How do i create them outside of dom and inject later ?

Comment: e.g. create a group with `group = new SVG.Group()` and later `group.addTo(selector)`. At least with svg.js v3

Comment: I have svg.js 2. I re did all th element creation with new SVG. .... But it doesent seem to be faster...